# Return object from reduce [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

i want return a list of object with reduce function.
I want a list of object like :

```
[{project: nameProj, hours: numProj}, {project: nameProj, hours: numProj},{project: nameProj, hours: numProj}]
```

Actually i return only a object where key is name of project and value is hours:

```
{
Name1: 9,
Name2: 10,
Name3: 30,
}
```

How i can return list of object from reduce function?

My actual code is:

```
this.activities$
        .pipe(map((e) => e.map((e) => e)))
        .subscribe((e) => (this.dati = e));
      this.aggregated = this.dati.reduce((acc: DataTable[], activity) => {
        const projectName = `${activity.project?.customer.name} - ${activity.project?.name}`;

        acc[projectName] = (acc[projectName] ?? 0) + activity.hours;
        return acc
        });
      }, {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It gets the keys as an array.

```
let sourceObj = {
 Name1: 9,
 Name2: 10,
 Name3: 30,
}

let formattedObj = Object.keys(sourceObj).map(k => { return { project: k, hours: sourceObj[k] } })
```